# error:428 When trying to checkout using Python

Tags: python, response, checkout, put, akamai

Im at the very last part of checkout for a bot. When I enter the information I constantly receive a 428 error.

```
"sec-cp-challenge": "true",
"provider": "crypto",
"branding_url_content": "%2fstatic%2fbot%2fchallenge%2findex.html",
"chlg_duration": 30
```

Here is a sample of the code used in checkout

```
headers = headers
cookies=cookies
data = data


response = session.put("https://api.nike.com/buy/checkouts/v3/" + ID, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are your headers?

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/428) indicate that response typically means that the server requires a precondition for the request.

I notice that you are using PUT method as well. Is this intended over POST? I can't find documentation on the API you're using.